# Th400 Transmission help

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, automatic-transmission

I pulled my Th400 out of my K20 Chevy and I'm in the middle of rebuilding it. I was reassembling it and when I went to put the completed gear train assembly in it, the centre support assembly gets stuck in the transmission case.  Can anyone here help?

Comment: Please provide more detailed information. Right now I have now idea what you mean.

Comment: Noah, register yourself as a user.  Right now, you have to access the site using the same web browser you used to access the site when you asked the question to maintain your identity.    Use the login and create an account.  Once you do that someone can help you merge this unregistered account with that one.  It will just be easier for you in the long run.  As well, If you could snap a couple of pics and jam them into your question I know there's a few people in here that would love to help  you with an issue like this.  Either way, the pics will help, as well as a little more explanation.

Comment: [Here is a video](https://youtu.be/-wdCVCnwzO4?t=3m27s) of Ian Johnson rebuilding one for Xtreme 4x4 ... I've started at where I believe you are having an issue ... can you confirm? If not, please help identify.

Comment: yes that is where I am having an issue.

Comment: Did you shim something? Did you put your gear clusters in correctly? Sounds like you put something in the wrong spot.

Comment: Ok every thing will drop in except the center support assembly gets caught up with the teeth on the transmission case and the teeth on the center support assembly because when I took everything out and just put the center support assembly in by its self and it still will not drop in all the way.

Comment: ok problem is solved

Comment: Kind of like Gilda Radner on SNL:  "Nevermind" . . .

Comment: How did you solve it?